# Better way to implement a validator than a number of if statements

Tags: typescript

I have a validator within my Angular app that is validating inputs of IP ranges to ensure the ranges are valid before they are submitted through a form. The validation itself all works fine but the general structure of the validator class leaves me wondering whether there is a better way to implement this.

A switch won't work for this particular scenario, so that's out of the question.

A simplified version of my validation method looks like this

```
validate(input: ipRange[]) { 
    for (let i = 0; i < ipRanges.length; i++) {
        let range1 = ipRange.range1;
        let range2 = ipRange.range2;

        if(!validatorRule1(range1) && !validatorRule1(range2) {
            //log ip range as invalid 
            continue;
        }

       if(!validatorRule2(range1) && !validatorRule2(range2) {
            //log ip range as invalid 
            continue;
        }

        etc...

        // log range as valid
    }
}
```

This is fine for a small amount of rules, but the method gets longer with each new rule that needs to be added. It's readable, but it doesn't look the most professional. What would be the best way to refactor this functionality so that it looked better?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make an array of methods representing validation rules, and then for each of those validation rules call them with ranges 1 and 2 as well as do logging. This way you replace a block of if calls with one if within a foreach. Does this make sense?